# Hot key for specific letter

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an easy way to make a new "global" hot key for a letter. I know that there are different ways of making hot keys for actions, but I have not found out how to make one for a given letter.

Specifically, I want to press "CTRL+C" to generate cedilla "ç" and "CTRL+SHIFT+C" to generate "Ç".

It does not have to be these specific keys, but the reason I am asking is that I want to buy a computer for a Portuguese speaker.

Edit: I am talking about a laptop.

Comment: Use a portuguese keyboard?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am talking about a laptop. I will edit the post. Thank you!

Comment: Use an external USB portuguese keyboard?

Comment: Yes, it's a good suggestion, but it is not really an option, since the laptop will be very mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to generate cedilla "ç" and "Ç"

Use the United States-International keyboard layout

---

#### Typing Diacritics And Special Characters

> Type International and Special Characters using the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or the following modifier keys: Apostrophe(<kbd>'</kbd>), Accent Grave(<kbd>`</kbd>), Quotation Mark(<kbd>"</kbd>), Tilde(<kbd>~</kbd>), and Circumflex(<kbd>^</kbd>). To type just the modifier key by itself, type <kbd>Space</kbd> following the modifier key. Press and hold the right <kbd>ALT</kbd> key then press the keys  to make the special characters:

[image]

Source [Microsoft Keyboards - English (US-International)
Typing Diacritics And Special Characters](http://www.forlang.wsu.edu/help/keyboards1.asp)

---

#### How to use the United States-International keyboard layout in Windows

> To add the United States-International keyboard layout, follow these
>   steps:
>
> Windows 7 or Windows Vista
>
> - Click Start button
> - Type intl.cpl in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
> - On the Keyboards and Language tab, click Change keyboards.
> - Click Add.
> - Expand the language that you want. For example, English (United States).
> - Expand Keyboard list, select the United States-International check box, and then click OK.
> - In the Default input language list, click Language name - United States-International (where Language name is the language that you
>     selected in step 4), and then click OK two times.
> - In the Regional and Language Options dialog box, click OK.
> - Notice that the Language bar appears on the taskbar. When you position the mouse pointer over it, a ToolTip appears that describes
>     the active keyboard layout.
> - Click the Language bar, and then click United States-International on the shortcut menu that appears.
>
> The United States-International keyboard layout is selected.

Source [How to use the United States-International keyboard layout in Windows 7, in Windows Vista, and in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306560)